# Detecting whether proving a predicate unified something

Tags: prolog, unification

I have a predicate that may unify its arguments, for example:

`foo(X) :- X = 42.`

How can I tell if, while proving `foo(X)`, unification changed X?  For example, I would like to know if `writeln(X), foo(X), writeln(X)` would print the same value for X twice, without actually doing the printing.

My actual implementation of `foo/1` is actually much more complex, so please don't suggest specific to the simplified version above.  In my program, `foo(X)` simplifies `X` using unification, but `foo(X)` may need to be proven several times until all simplifications have been performed.  I would like to be able to write a `foohelper(X)` predicate that invokes `foo(X)` until `X` stops being unified.

Comment: **When** do you want to tell if `X` has been instantiated? (We do not change `X`, we instantiate it)

Comment: I want to know if `X` was instantiated while proving `foo(X)`, at the location of the second `writeln(X)` in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the standard `term_variables/2` predicate? You can call it with your goal before and after calling the goal and check if the returned lists of variables are different. Something like:

```
...,
term_variables(foo(X), Vars0),
foo(X),
term_variables(foo(X), Vars),
(  Vars0 == Vars ->
   write(simplified)
;  write(not_simplified)
),
...
```

Comment: "simplified" should rather be "identical"

Comment: @false Read the question. There you will find why I used the word "simplified".

Comment: I think this should work -- thanks!  I'm curious if there are any better ways to take a "snapshot" of a term.

Comment: @EdMcMan You could use in alternative the standard `copy_term/2` predicate to take what you call a snapshot of a term and then use this snapshot together with the standard `subsumes_term/2` predicate but that would be a more verbose and costly solution.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we have only syntactic unification - that is, no constraints:

```
:- meta_predicate(call_instantiated(0,?)).

call_instantiated(Goal_0, Instantiated) :-
    copy_term(Goal_0, Copy_0),
    Goal_0,
    (  subsumes_term(Goal_0, Copy_0) ->  % succeeds iff equal u.t.r.
       Instantiated = false
    ;  Instantiated = true
    ).
```

Note that `Goal_0` will or will not be further instantiated.  The above `subsumes_term/2` tests whether or not `Goal_0` is now "more general" than `Copy_0`. Of course, it cannot be more general, so effectively that test tests whether or not the terms are identical up to renaming of variables.

Compared to using `term_variables/2`, as @PauloMoura has indicated, this may more may not be more efficient. It primarily depends on the efficiency of `subsumes_term/2`.

Comment: `Goal_0` should be `call(Goal_0)`. Bad programming style using naked (meta-)variables. Also, their semantics may or may not be equivalent to `call/1` depending on the Prolog system (w.r.t. being opaque or transparent to cuts).

Comment: @PauloMoura ?? That is well-defined behavior. Which Prolog system does not handle this correctly?

Comment: Is not a question of correctness but a question of chosen semantics for naked meta-variables. ECLiPSe is an example of a system where naked meta-variables are transparent to cuts.

Comment: @PauloMoura: Maybe there is some difference sometimes. But there is *no* difference for this case. Say: `mynot(X) :- X, !, fail. mynot(_)`. correctly succeeds with `mynot((!,fail))` in Eclipse (default mode).

Comment: In this case (naked meta-variables), good programming style is also defensive programming.